# Using pointer to char array, values in that array can be accessed?

Tags: c, pointers

I created ptr as pointer to an array of 5 chars.

```
char (*ptr)[5];
```

assigned it the address of a char array.

```
char arr[5] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
ptr = &arr;
```

using pointer ptr can I access the char values in this array?

```
printf("\nvalue:%c", *(ptr+0));
```

It does not print the value.

In my understanding ptr will contain the base address of array but it actually point to the memory required for the complete array (i.e 5 chars). Thus when ptr is incremented it moves ahead by `sizeof(char)*5` bytes. So is it not possible to access values of the array using this pointer to array?

Comment: Please remember to accept the correct answer to your question which helped you the most. You accept questions with the tick mark next to it.

Comment: Everyone, pretty please read this http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ptrtoarray.html before posting an answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you want to access an element, you have to first dereference your pointer, and then index the element you want (which is also dereferncing). i.e. you need to do:

`printf("\nvalue:%c", (*ptr)[0]);` , which is the same as `*((*ptr)+0)`

Note that working with pointer to arrays are not very common in C. instead, one just use a pointer to the first element in an array, and either deal with the length as a separate element, or place a senitel value at the end of the array, so one can learn when the array ends, e.g.

```
char arr[5] = {'a','b','c','d','e',0}; 
char *ptr = arr; //same as char *ptr = &arr[0]

printf("\nvalue:%c", ptr[0]);
```

Comment: Array pointers have their (limited) uses, for example they are useful when declaring multi-dimensional arrays dynamically and you want the memory declared adjacently. So I wouldn't dismiss them entirely. But as we can see from this thread, most C programmers are clueless about them, so that alone is a reason to stay away from then.

Answer (score 10):

Most people responding don't even seem to know what an array pointer is...

The problem is that you do pointer arithmetics with an array pointer: ptr + 1 will mean "jump 5 bytes ahead since ptr points at a 5 byte array".

Do like this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char (*ptr)[5];
  char arr[5] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
  int i;

  ptr = &arr;
  for(i=0; i<5; i++)
  {
    printf("\nvalue: %c", (*ptr)[i]);
  }
}
```

Take the contents of what the array pointer points at and you get an array. So they work just like any pointer in C.

Answer (score 0):

Your should create ptr as follows:

```
char *ptr;
```

You have created ptr as an array of pointers to chars. The above creates a single pointer to a char.

Edit: complete code should be:

```
char *ptr;
char arr[5] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
ptr = arr;
printf("\nvalue:%c", *(ptr+0));
```

Comment: `char (*ptr)[5]` is a pointer to array, and `char *ptr[5]` is array of pointers.

Comment: The OP asked about array pointers specifically. So I suspect that they know how to use plain pointers and arrays already.

Answer (score 0):

**Use of pointer before character array**

Normally, Character array is used to store single elements in it i.e 1 byte each

eg:

```
char a[]={'a','b','c'};
```

we can't store multiple value in it.

by using pointer before the character array we can store the multi dimensional array elements in the array

i.e.

```
char *a[]={"one","two","three"};
printf("%s\n%s\n%s",a[0],a[1],a[2]);
```